# How to automatically find the upstream URL for a fork on GitHub without hub?

Tags: git, github

After forking and cloning a repository on GitHub, one usually [configures an upstream remote for the fork](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/):

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPO.git
```

Is there a way of finding the upstream URL automatically (programmatically) **without using [hub](https://hub.github.com/)** so I can create an alias (or a script) for the above command?

Comment: What have you tried so far? GitHub has reasonably complete [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/), which is exactly what `hub` uses.  It seems like there might be something useful there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the result of `https://api.github.com/repos/FORK_OWNER/FORK_REPO` and extract the key `parent -> clone_url`.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the answer of @Vampire, you can add the following bash function to `~/.bashrc` :

```sh
function add_upstream() {
    url=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
    repoWithOwnerExt=${url#*github.com[/:]}
    repoWithOwner=${repoWithOwnerExt%.git}
    remote=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/$repoWithOwner" | jq -r '.parent.clone_url')
    if [ "$remote" != "null" ]; then
        git remote add upstream "$remote"
    else
        echo "no upstream found"
    fi
}
```

It's extracting user and repo value, and using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser to parse `.parent.clone_url`.

Then, use it with `add_upstream` command

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing great script. Unfortunately, the script does not work now. It works if the "repo" variable is changed to "repo=$(basename ${url##*/} .git)".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Github-Enterprise, then the [api endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository) is bit different -

```
https://${hostname}/api/v3/repos/${user}/${repository-name}
```

And then you extract the key `parent -> clone_url`

If you want to use authentication then

```
curl -u <github_username>:<github_token> https://${hostname}/api/v3/repos/${user}/${repository-name}
```

[Github-token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/extending-github/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens)